# Best practices in writing orm.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, orm

I am new to orm. I am using spring and hibernate:
1) I found that we can have seperate classname.hbm.xml file for mapping the classes to the db. I also saw people using single orm.xml for the same. Can anyone say which is the best way to do it when we have plenty of tables with relationships. 
2) And also I saw mappings are done within the class too,using @Id , @Column etc . Is there any advantage  in doing so. Please suggest which is the best way to follow keeping in mind there is a pretty good chance that modifications in db are likely to come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** There is no difference. You can do the same things with both approaches.

** With annotations you have mapping directly together in java.

** Xml mapping files give a better overview over the table and its mapping.

If you have repeated changes in your code go through with HBM.Xml file otherwise Go with Annotations.

Comment: So lets say my requirement needs me to go for xml.And in it when we practice keeping seperate classname.hbm.xml instead of a single orm.xml??

Comment: In my view use separate classname.hbm.xml file for better understanding for others

Comment: I just heard using xml is an old hibernate technique and we use annotations these days. So obviously there is some advantage for it na?

Comment: @RBz Correct before Java1.5 they used xml files. And here you don't need to create xml files. We don't care about creating an Entity classes. By using revers-engine mechanism we can create.